# Stuck between errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

i am a absolute beginner and practicing with this project "guessing the number" i have wrote the following code and wanna know what kind of error i have made.

```
import random
guess_count = 3
number = random.randint(1, 9)

while guess_count > 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    guess_count -= 1


    if guess == number:
        print("Congrats You Won!")
        guess_count = 0
    else:
        print("You Lose, Better luck next time.")
        print('')
        print(f"The correct number was {number}.")
```

Output comes out to be this,

```
Guess: 2
You Lose, Better luck next time.

The correct number was 6.
Guess:  6
Congrats You Won!
```

Expected output for failure :

```
  Guess: 3
  Guess: 4
  Guess: 5
You Lose, Better luck next time.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I would also suggest sticking to either double- or single-quotes in your `print` statements.

Comment: I recommend using a code formatting tool. I'm personally a big fan of https://github.com/python/black,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `break` to end the loop when the guess is correct.

Put the `else:` block on the `while` loop. It will be executed if the loop ends without a `break`, which happens when they run out of guesses.

```
import random
guess_count = 3
number = random.randint(1, 9)

while guess_count > 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    guess_count -= 1

    if guess == number:
        print("Congrats You Won!")
        break
else:
    print("You Lose, Better luck next time.")
    print('')
    print(f"The correct number was {number}.")
```

Answer (score 1):

import random
guess_count = 3
number = random.randint(1, 9)

```
while guess_count > 0:
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))
    guess_count -= 1


    if guess == number:
        print("Congrats You Won!")
        guess_count = 0
    else:
        print("You Lose, Better luck next time.")
        print('')
        print("The correct number was ", number , " .")
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your answer to fix the formatting, and write a little bit on how this wil best solve the issue OP is having.

Comment: Just fixed some bugs in the last line... hope somebody may help you out more. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to format the problem, using a for loop instead:

```
import random

guess_count = 3
number = random.randint(1, 9)

for x in range(0, guess_count):
    guess = int(input("Guess: "))

    if guess == number:
        print("Congrats You Won!")
        break # exit loop
    else:
        print("You Lose, Better luck next time.")
        print('')

        if x == guess_count - 1:
            print(f"The correct number was {number}.")
```